# How to get HID profile connected to iOS device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I want to check whether the BlueTooth device is the device I want by the HID(Human Interface Device) profile.

Is it possible??

And how to get the HID profile?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean by selecting device visually?

Comment: @Owl Don't need to select them.I want to get the profile details to judge whether it is the device my app want.Because my company want to make a app that only can use our BlueTooth device.

Comment: When you send packets for connection, I guess you can specify company ID. If you have done any GameKit programming it shows that only an app is able to a similar app. Same way I guess ot should be possibe but at very low level.

Comment: @Owl Does GameKit could connect with a device without iOS in there??I have no experiment about GameKit.I saw some samples about it, but they are all about to connect with iPhone or iPad. I have no idea about it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments, I do understand your request like that: You want to write an iOS app that takes input from a device connected via Bluetooth using the HID profile. Input from other, similar devices shall not be accepted by the app.

A first answer is: You can't do that. [Bluetooth HID connections are established](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHhc2p7gZxE) at OS level by

- Tap "Settings", choose "General" > "Bluetooth"
- Switch Bluetooth on
- Turn on your Bluetooth input device
- Select your remote input device within your iOS device's Bluetooth device discovery and pair booth devices

Once, the input device is connected, it works as it is supposed to: Sending input events (in case of a keyboard characters / control signals). On app level you are not able to access low level data, like Bluetooth address, manufacturer information and so on. Gamekit will not help. It is higher level than OS level and requires an iOS device with an appropriate app on the remote side as well.

On a second thought, as you are developing the remote Bluetooth input device as well, you may go higher level. You connect the device as described above, but you encrypt the data the input device sends to a mobile device. Your app decrypts data and you problem is solved. Third party devices don't use your protocol and can't talk to your app. (So your app will have ignore their inputs). But this approach will break compatibility with other devices not using your app (e.g. you can't get a Bluetooth keyboard working with a regular pc anymore).

Comment: OMG,thanks for your help~~ About the second thought, I don't know how to connect with a Bluetooth device.Is it possible by using the Gamekit??

Comment: Just follow the video link or the bullet point list to connect an iOS device to a remote device by Bluetooth. Please note, that these steps are done outside your planned app.

Gamekit requires an iOS device on the other side. Additionally, Gamekit does not allow to utilize HID profile. It is a protocol of its own.

What kind of input device do you plan to use?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to make the app.I have no idea about which framework to use. Could you give some advise about it?? tips: External Accessory Framework needs a MFi device,and my company won't go with this way... Thanks for your help~~

Comment: The MFi program would be a professional way, but if single way data transmission from an external input device to an iOS device, HID profile will be sufficient. In latter case app development will be rather simple. Input device will be connected on OS level, on app level you just add a textfield set as first responder. All data should drop in non-interactivly, as there is no feedback from app to input device possible due to HID constraints.

Comment: Um,yes,it is.Do you know how to receive data from a external device on the app level??I mean which framework to use??

Comment: Your input device may technically behave like a keyboard. It just does not have usual keys, but your own design. As soon as there is input data available to send, just send it. Within the app it appears, that the user hits keys on this virtual keyboard. By implementing a protocol of your own, you can gain more control on what data is sent a certain point of time.

Comment: Yah,I see your thought and the process.But I'm still a little confused by how to connect the iOS device with the Bluetooth device on code side.Do you have some sample about it??I can't find them out...Big appreciation to you~

Comment: You can't connect the iOS device the remote device by Bluetooth on app level (at least not with a non-jailbroken device). The connection has to be established on OS level, outside your app - just like the video link of my answer shows. The only commercially suitable alternative on iOS devices is the MFi program. But this is not an easy way to go, as you need to apply for membership with uncertain acceptance.

Comment: Ah~~ I see~~ Thanks for your answer~~